# DB2: How to filter based on the result obtained from CASE condition

Tags: sql, database, db2

I am trying to filter the data based on the results obtained from previous CASE condition in `DB2`:

Below is the initial query to filter the data:

```
SELECT EM.NAME,EM.ID,EM.DIV
CASE DEPT
WHEN '1' THEN 'FIN'
WHEN '2' THEN 'MKT'
WHEN '3' THEN 'IT'
WHEN '4' THEN 'HR' END AS DEPT_DESC
FROM EMPLOYEE_RCD EM;
```

Sample Data:

```
NAME    ID    DIV   DEPT_DESC
MICHAEL 3334   3    IT
SAMUEL  100922 1    FIN
ORINDA  7363   1    FIN
SARA    8383   2    MKT
RACHAEL 8383   4    HR
MARTIN  33312  
SUZY    993    NA   NA
MIKE    576    NULL NULL
```

What I tried to filter the results:

```
SELECT EM.NAME,EM.ID,EM.DIV
CASE DEPT
WHEN '1' THEN 'FIN'
WHEN '2' THEN 'MKT'
WHEN '3' THEN 'IT'
WHEN '4' THEN 'HR' END AS DEPT_DESC
CASE DEPT_DESC
WHEN DEPT_DESC == ''   THEN 'No Dept'
WHEN DEPT_DESC == NA   THEN 'No Dept'
WHEN DEPT_DESC == NULL THEN 'No Dept'
FROM EMPLOYEE_RCD EM;
```

but not getting the results instead getting errors:

```
[Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "== ''" was found following "WHEN DEPT_DESC".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29
```

Any help in, how to filter the data and get the below result:

Expected 0/P:

```
NAME    ID    DIV   DEPT_DESC
MARTIN  33312  
SUZY    993    NA   NA
MIKE    576    NULL NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `CASE` the wrong way:

- Each `WHEN` clause needs to be followed by a [boolean] condition.
- Use single equal `=` for equality, not double equal `==`.
- If you want to use a pre-computed column to process it again, you can use a subquery.

Your query should probably look like:

```
select name, id, div,
    CASE
    WHEN DEPT_DESC = ''   THEN 'No Dept'
    WHEN DEPT_DESC = NA   THEN 'No Dept'
    WHEN DEPT_DESC = NULL THEN 'No Dept'
    END as dept_desc
  from ( -- subquery runs first
    SELECT EM.NAME,EM.ID,EM.DIV
    CASE 
    WHEN DIV = '1' THEN 'FIN'
    WHEN DIV = '2' THEN 'MKT'
    WHEN DIV = '3' THEN 'IT'
    WHEN DIV = '4' THEN 'HR' END AS DEPT_DESC
    FROM EMPLOYEE_RCD EM
  ) x    
;
```

Comment: `CASE colname WHEN value1 THEN expression1 WHEN value2 THEN expression2 ...` is a valid, if less commonly used and more restrictive form of `CASE`

Comment: @PaulVernon Oh. You learn something new every day. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: But otherwise, you are correct, using a sub-query is the way to go here. Unless that is you use SQL_COMPT=NPS where you can reference a previous calculated column or alias later on in the same select list, but really that is just for Netezza compatibility purposes

Answer (score 2):

In the example given, you only need one case statement

```
SELECT  EM.NAME
,       EM.ID
,       EM.DIV
,       CASE DEPT
            WHEN '1' THEN 'FIN'
            WHEN '2' THEN 'MKT'
            WHEN '3' THEN 'IT'
            WHEN '4' THEN 'HR' 
                     ELSE 'No Dept' END AS DEPT_DESC
FROM
    EMPLOYEE_RCD EM
```

BTW If you use a SQL editor that can parse your SQL as you write it (e.g. the free IBM Data Studio), it is easier to spot and fix syntax errors.